# Background color in dropdrop, shinyWidgets

Tags: css, r, shiny

How do I change the color of the dropdown menu from `shinyWidgets` (not the buttom, but the opened menu). I assume, I need some CSS code, but I don't have very much CSS experience.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
n <- 200

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  dropdown(
    tags$h4("Advanced"),
    icon = icon("gear"),
    status = "primary", width = "600px",
    inputId="dropdown"
  ),
  tags$style(HTML('#dropdown {background-color: red;}')),
  plotOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$n))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `#sw-content-dropdown, .sw-dropdown-in`, e.g. :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
n <- 200

ui <- bootstrapPage(

  dropdown(
    tags$h4("Advanced"),
    numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
    icon = icon("gear"),
    status = "primary", width = "600px",
    inputId="dropdown"
  ),
  tags$style(HTML('#sw-content-dropdown, .sw-dropdown-in {background-color: red;}')),
  plotOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$n))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. How did you figure out the `#sw-content-dropdown, .sw-dropdown-in` part?

Comment: I wrote the function ;) . I'll update documentation to be more precise !